# Can Visual Studio be made to debug child processes like WinDBG?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, child-process

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448154/automatically-attach-vs2005-debugger-to-a-child-processes), but I wanted to flesh it out a bit.  (I'm new here, if I should instead do a "bump" answer on the previous question instead, please let me know.)

In WinDBG, I can use the `.childdbg 1` command to tell it to break when a child process is spawned, or I can launch it with the `-o` command-line option.  This is very useful in some situations, so it's surprising that (as far as I can see) Visual Studio doesn't support it.  It seems like it ought to be pretty easy to clear the `DEBUG_PROCESS_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` flag on CreateProcess(), and VS already supports debugging multiple processes.

So, am I missing some option in Visual Studio to enable this?  If not, is there a technical rationale for why they have chosen not to support it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not possible (AFAIK, any many others...) but you have several workarounds:

1. [Use this macro](http://web.archive.org/web/20150603120222/http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/WindowsVisualStudioMacros#Automatically_grab_chromium_child_processes), it comes from the Chrome team which need to deal with a lot of child processes debugging.
2. Put your child process on [Image Execution Options](http://blogs.msdn.com/greggm/archive/2005/02/21/377663.aspx) so that they will automatclly open in a debugger. Then select the current active instance of Visual Studio.

Comment: The "Use this macro" links appear to be broken -- could you update the answer to include the macro instead of linking to it?

Comment: Neither of the links appear to reference anything useful now. This is exactly why link-centric answers aren't great.

Answer (score 41):

There is now a power tool that lets you attach to child process:
[Introducing The Child Process Debugging Power Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool)

[image: Child process debugging menu]