# How Debug program called by another program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I Have written Two programs in C++, A and B. In the A program I call B with arguments (console Based Program).

What I want is when I call B want to be in the debug mode (known that I run the program A). How could I set that in the Visual Studio 2010 ?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Visual Studio be made to debug child processes like WinDBG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771039/can-visual-studio-be-made-to-debug-child-processes-like-windbg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I have had the same issue I just added `Sleep(10000)`; (or similarly) at the start of program B and then manually attached a debugger. You can also make that conditional on an environment variable/command line argument/...

I know that it is a hack - but it sort of works; and would also prefer a better solution.

Comment: It is a hack, and requires that you *can* change the code for program B. Better solutions exist. The proposed duplicate offers two such solutions.

Comment: @IInspectable Depending on circumstances there might be better solutions, but the chrome-macro-link was dead, and the Image Execution Options means changing the registry back and forth. The child process tool seems to require VS 2013 Update 2; or later - and OP used VS 2010.

Comment: Writing a batch script to enable and disable the Image Execution Options is a matter of 2 minutes. It's convenient, too, because you don't have to manually go looking for the process to attach the debugger to. In addition, it is the only way to go forward, if you need to debug startup code.

Answer (score -1):

In program B at the start of main call `::DebugBreak()`  this will allow you to attach the debugger to your 2nd process. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: No, this won't work. `DebugBreak()` breaks into the debugger, when a debugger is already attached. This is straight from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297.aspx): *"If the process is not being debugged, the function uses the search logic of a standard exception handler. In most cases, this causes the calling process to terminate because of an unhandled breakpoint exception."*

Comment: that made my prog crashes at the call !!

Comment: I get a nice dialog box, paraphrasing "An exception has occurred.  Do you want to Abort, Retry, Debug the process?"

Comment: @RichardCritten: Yes, you do. **If** a debugger is already attached.